# Spring boot fetch data check req in logic and release lock

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

how in spring boot can I make thing like:

```
appSettingsRepository.findOneOrderByIdDesc()
```

with some logic :

```
        if (appSettings.getLastTestDate().plusHours(1).isBefore(now)) {
        appSettings.setLastTestDate(now);
        appSettingsRepository.save(appSettings);
```

to be done inside pesimistic lock ?

I dont want to allow other node even to query this settings.
After releasing lock other node will see new test date, and just wont do anything due do this if else logic.

Answer (score 0):

ah I used finally
https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

it does what I wanted to do, but its easy to be done using annotations